# Singularity and behaviour at infinity for complex function

Tags: complex-analysis, infinity

I'm suppose to check the singularities and behaviour at infinity. However, I've never seen that and couln't find something about it online.
So i have a function
$ f(z) = \frac{1}{\exp{(z)} -1)}-\frac{1}{z}$

My attempt:
expand in the variable: $u = \frac{1}{z}$.

So we have:

$f(u) = \frac{1}{\exp(\frac{1}{u})-1}-u$

Now I think I am supposed to do an Laurent expansion around $u=0$? But I am not sure.

Would love your input!

Comment: It has a singularity at each of the points $2n\pi i$ so $\infty$ is not an islolated singularity of $f$.

Comment: Thank you. How do you do questions like this? is there a general method?

Comment: The usual classification of sigularities is for isolated singularities. So it is not clear as to what kind of answer is expected here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way goes as follows:

First rewrite the function $f(z)=\frac{1}{\exp(z)-1}-\frac{1}{z}$ as a Laurent series.

Notice that the $\frac{1}{z}$ part is already in the form of a Laurent series so we just need to rewrite the $\frac{1}{\exp(z)-1}$ part. This is done by solving the equation:
$\frac{1}{\exp(z)-1}=g(x)$ iff $g(x)\cdot(\exp(z)-1)=g(x)\cdot(1+z+\frac{z^2}{2}+O(z)-1)=1$. This part takes practice and you need to try it out for yourself but basically you write $g(x)$ term by term so that the terms cancel with the terms from the other factor. The first two terms in each should equal one and all others should equal $0$ since you have no $z$'s on the right hand side.

You should get:
$(\frac{1}{z}-\frac{1}{2}+\frac{z}{4}+O(z^2))(z+\frac{z^2}{2!}+\frac{z^3}{3!}+O(z^4))=1$.
Now you put this back into the function $f$ and you get:
$f(z)=\frac{1}{z}-\frac{1}{2}+\frac{z}{4}+O(z^2)-\frac{1}{z}=-\frac{1}{2}+\frac{z}{4}+O(z^2)$.
Now you see that you have no $z^k$ terms for some $k<0$. This tells you that you have a removable singularity. That is not always the case. The Laurent series form should tell you what type of singularity you are dealing with. It will not always be a removable singularity as you have found here and calculating the Laurent series will not always be the best way to tackle the problem. I hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you for Helping me. I havent seen that method before. What is it called? I would love to read more about it

Comment: I don't think this "recipe" has a name or if it does I'm not aware of it. I suggest that you don't read up about this but find some similar exercises and practice solving them.
Note (the rest of the recipe): I mentioned that you do not always end up with a Laurent series with no $z^k$ for $k<0$. If there are finitely many $z^k$ with $k<0$ the singularity is a pole of order $k'$ where $k'$ is the smallest $k$ for which you have a $z^k$ term. The last case is when you have infinitely many $z^k$ terms for $k<0$ . In that case your function has a essential singularity in 0.